# Making HTML mobile compliant

Tags: html, css, w3-css

I am using CSS stylesheet offered by W3Schools.com for designing my front end and it has a class property by the name "w3-rightbar" which provides right border with thick line. I want this "w3-rightbar" to be hidden on the mobile view. So I used the below CSS script to achieve that,

```
<style>
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
  .w3-rightbar { display: none; }
}
</style>
```

```
<div class="w3-quarter w3-container w3-rightbar w3-border-white w3-mobile" style="width: 25%;height: 300px;text-align: justify;" >
      <h3><b>Div 1 </b></h3>
      <p>
       Div 1 content
      </p> 
    </div>
    <div class="w3-quarter w3-container w3-mobile" style="width: 25%;text-align: justify;">
      <h3><b>Div 2</b></h3>
      <p>
       DIV 2 content
      </p>
    </div>
```

But what's happening is, it's setting the entire content of the Div 1 along with the right bar to none. I only want the right bar to be set to 'none'.

Comment: "*I only want the right bar to be set to 'none'.*" - What do you mean with this? Does this mean you only want to remove the border?

Comment: You probably need to set `border: 0;` rather than `display: none;`, but without seeing the relevant parts of your code we can’t be sure.

Comment: This is the div I am talking about "<div class="w3-quarter w3-container w3-rightbar w3-border-white w3-mobile" style="width: 25%; height: 340px; text-align: justify;" >". It has a class by the name w3-rightbar and it introduces a thick border of color white next to the div content

Comment: Please provide further details and code by [editting](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/77199611/edit) the question rather than posting them in the comments. Also check out the comment of Brett

Answer (score 0):

```css
<style>
@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {
    .w3-rightbar { border: none; }
}
</style>
```

rightbar sets a border property, so this should get rid of it on mobile